# If cards exiled by Karn, Scion of Urza enter the graveyard/battlefield, do they still have the silver counter?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have a [Karn, Scion of Urza](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKarn%2c%20Scion%20of%20Urza%5d). I tick up, and one card gets exiled with a silver counter. Later, that card is processed by [Wasteland Strangler](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWasteland%20Strangler%5d), reanimated by [Reanimate](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bReanimate%5d), and then re-exiled by [Swords to Plowshares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSwords%20to%20Plowshares%5d).

Can I now tick down Karn to add that card to my hand? That is, after all these interactions, does that card still have a silver counter? If not, at what point does the card lose the silver counter?

What if the card that's exiled is [Eternal Scourge](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEternal%20Scourge%5d), and I choose to cast it from exile - does the Eternal Scourge enter the battlefield with a silver counter?

Comment: Counters aren't tokens and tokens aren't counters.

Comment: Eternal Scourge can't be exiled by Karn to begin with, because getting targeted by Karn triggers its triggered ability, and it then exiles itself before Karn's ability resolves, causing Karn's ability to fizzle.

Comment: @nick012000 Karn doesn't have a way to target an in-play Eternal Scourge, and can definitely exile Eternal Scourge when it ticks up.

Comment: @Allure *double checks the Karn in the link* Oh, I thought it was the other Karn that exiled things in play.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the counter does not stay on the card in situations like those. [Rule 122.2](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Counter_(marker)) says

> Counters on an object are not retained if that object moves from one zone to another. The counters are not “removed”; they simply cease to exist. See rule 400.7.